# Concurrent Modification Exception when using springframework mongotemplate findone api

Tags: mapping, spring-data-mongodb, mongotemplate

If I run my program in a single thread, I am not seeing any exception. The problem occurs only in a multithread environment, where multiple threads are reading and writing on/to the same collection simultaneously. I do not have a fixed test case as this is occurring randomly in different places of my code. It is happening on same API where I am using `FindOne` function call to fetch one record from the database.

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
        at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:859)
        at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:831)
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.doWithProperties(BasicPersistentEntity.java:305)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:266)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:230)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.readCollectionOrArray(MappingMongoConverter.java:898)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.readValue(MappingMongoConverter.java:1159)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.access$200(MappingMongoConverter.java:77)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$MongoDbPropertyValueProvider.getPropertyValue(MappingMongoConverter.java:1110)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.getValueInternal(MappingMongoConverter.java:861)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$1.doWithPersistentProperty(MappingMongoConverter.java:278)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$1.doWithPersistentProperty(MappingMongoConverter.java:266)
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.doWithProperties(BasicPersistentEntity.java:307)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:266)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:230)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:190)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:186)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:77)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate$ReadDbObjectCallback.doWith(MongoTemplate.java:2128)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.executeFindOneInternal(MongoTemplate.java:1766)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFindOne(MongoTemplate.java:1582)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.findOne(MongoTemplate.java:497)
```

Comment: can you provide any code example?

Answer (score 1):

You are running a multi-threaded code with a non-thread safe function. You will need to add locks in order to prevent acces from multiple threads to the same data.